# Why does my Wonder Pot now bake unevenly?

Tags: baking, equipment, stove

I've been using a [Wonder Pot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Pot) for a year and a half, mainly making cake and the occasional bread.

Recently my cakes have started baking unevenly, with one half of the pot completing the baking before the other half. I usually end up turning the pot 180 degrees when it is a little more than half done, in order to evenly bake. This was not an issue when I was first using it.

Anyone experienced with Wonder Pots know why this might start happening, and what can be done to fix it?

I have recently changed stovetops, and it is possible I'm not getting the flame height right, or the positioning (although it is pretty centered).

It was already used when I got it, so perhaps the [metal disc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wonder_Pot_metal_disc.jpg) is worn out and no longer distributing the heat evenly. (Does that even happen)?

You can see pictures of the top and bottom of my disc here. I'm not sure if corrosion or rust is the right way to describe it, but you can see that there is some kind of something on the disc, and it appears a little uneven. It doesn't seem all that different from the picture on wikipedia, though.

[image: pic_top] [image: pic_bottom]

Comment: It's such a simple item, it's hard to think what could be wrong with it that wouldn't be obvious. Have you checked your stove?

Comment: @Satanicpuppy: I checked the stove and the flame is small and even, it is possible that the whole stove is slightly elevated to one side, I'll check again. I also added pictures of my metal disc

Comment: Can you ask a friend to borrow their stove and cook something there? Just to see if it's really your pot that is the issue? Like Satanicpuppy, I find myself thinking the pot itself is just too simple to have a problem that isn't obvious (like a chunk missing).

Answer (score 4):

Your flame may *look* even, but check the heat diffuser component of your wonderpot in your photo - you see the sootmark? That's a [clear indication](http://www.aham.org/consumer/ht/a/GetDocumentAction/id/841)[PDF document from Association of Home Appliance Manufacturers] that the flame isn't burning cleanly... soot is made of carbon byproducts that should have been consumed by a clean burning flame, which consists of both fuel (cooking gas) and air. The burner's job is to combine both to make a clean flame. That much soot means it's not burning efficiently, which leads to uneven heat.

It can also lead to the production of carbon monoxide, which is *not* a good thing.

You will need to clean and calibrate the burner so it produces a clean, pure blue-white flame that burns clean on the bottom of your pots, or replace it if that doesn't help. This should only be done by someone knowledgeable in gas appliance repair.

Comment: that soot mark was created by another stove. Also, I'd have to check if the uneven cooking matches up with the mark

Answer (score 2):

On close inspection of my stovetop, I think I may have found the source of the problem. The burner was off-center. I re-positioned it and the problem went away almost entirely. I just have to fiddle with it a little longer until I get it exactly centered.

Here's a picture of the burner:
[image: off-center burner]